# problem with localhost And 127.0.0.1 on ethernet network in ubuntu OS 14.04

Tags: networking, vmware, localhost

I have two computers on my network and both are running Ubuntu.
The server (192.168.61.150):
When I enter in the browser address is `http://localhost` to my site loaded correctly.
But when I write `http://127.0.0.1` address blank page is loaded.
I want the client to access my `localhost` server system.
But when I enter the client in the browser address `http://192.168.61.150` white page is loaded.

Comment: Is the server running inside a VMware machine?

Comment: @MadMike hi, server is a VMware machine

Comment: Is the virtual interface NAT or Bridge?

Comment: @MadMike is Bridge , I have ping from both sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can access localhost by typing either `http://localhost` or the actual ip address of the host (open terminal and run 'ifconfig' to find out correct ip of the specific computer host. ip must be set to static, by the way, in order for you to access always through the same address.
Type `http://192.168.61.(machine)`